# Java Applet not loading without internet

Tags: java, php, javascript, applet, sip

I am using MizuTech webphone
 when i run it using WAMP server of and other server it says **cannot find java applet handler..!**.
But if i connect my internet it works fine.
Can you please tell is it necessary for Java applet to use Internet ?
If not could you please tell me how I can get rid from it.

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely run an applet without being connected to the internet.

... as long as all of its jars and code are available locally.

Comment: Yes .jar and code saved locally. Also by just time my localhost URL it work fine but if i press [F5] or refresh button it stop working because by simply opening URL its loading web page from cashes.

Answer (score 0):

While it may be possible to load the applet from local sources, my understanding of SIP calls is that they generally go via the internet.  So the main point of a 'SIP phone applet' is lost when there is no internet connection.  It is a like a mobile phone with no signal, or a land-line phone when 'the storm has brought down the phone lines'.

Comment: I am having my own SIP server. Applet is unable to load without calling and register function.